# Mule Salesforce Analytics Connector Requirements does not match the schema

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, sfdc

We are using the Mulesoft sfdc-analytics connector. When we installed the connector into Anypoint Stuido and used the connector's Operation "Create data set", the connector requires additional attributes one of those being Operation; however, in the schema (http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-analytics-connector/1.0.0/mule/sfdc-analytics-schema.html) the create-data-set element does not have "operation" defined so when we go to run the application package fails with the follow issue:

```
INFO  2017-04-01 22:21:28,431 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
ERROR 2017-04-01 22:21:28,493 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'operation' is not allowed to appear in element 'sfdc-analytics:create-data-set'.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are using an **old** version of the Salesforce Analytics Connector. That schema belongs to version 1.0.0 which does not have the "operation" element. That property was added in **version 2.0.0** (latest is 2.1.0), as stated in the official [Release Notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/salesforce-analytics-cloud-connector-release-notes). And the related schema is [here](http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-analytics-connector/2.0.0/mule/sfdc-analytics-schema.html).

Comment: The connector I installed was 2.1. When I request the LATEST in my pom.xml it throws the same error. I had to explicitly request 2.0.0.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is because I don't have a settings.xml file setup to pull from the enterprise repository so it falls back to version 1.0 which apparently doesn't require enterprise access.

Comment: Try with RELEASE, that should bring you the most recent version (LATEST is for SNAPSHOTS). Indee, in your settings.xml you'll need to setup the enteprise repository credentials for: <repository> <id>mule-ee-releases</id> <name>MuleSoft Repository</name> <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/re‌​positories/releases-‌​ee/</url> <layout>default</layout> </repository>. More info here